# Matlab unable to format string to path

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

In original script there is part of code where is this

```
filepathsource='C:\Users\...';
strFP=dir([filepathsource '*.txt']);
```

Which works nicely.
Problem is that i need to change that filepathsource to some more dynamic so i did.

```
filepathsource=string(strcat(app.folderPath,'\',string(app.currentCount),'\'));
strFP=dir([filepathsource '*.txt']);
```

But i end with error

```
Error using dir
Name must be a text scalar.
```

And i need original formating because i get errors later in script. Is there any way how can i fix it? I tried everything but always is something somewhere wrong. And i just dont understand whats difference between original `filepathsource` and the one that i created bot are strings. (output of my filepathsource is correct when i display it)

Comment: `char` variable types and `string` variable types are not the same, you seem to be casting everything to a `string` and then expecting them to behave like a `char`. Remove the `string` castings, use `fullfile` instead of manually adding file separators, and make sure `filepathsource` is a char (which `dir` expects) to avoid the error

Comment: @Wolfie Yeah thanks it seems that was the problem. Thank you again :)